# PHP Search Not Working When I Get To The While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, forms, loops, search

I had a search form for my website which worked perfectly fine, but I then changed my entire login system and it cause a few errors within my site. The only error now that I cant seem to fix is the search forms within my website. Which i thought was weird because the form doesnt use any of the variables from the login form. When I was testing to find out the issue I found out that when the part of my search script gets to the while loop it breaks on me. If you have any suggestions or help it would be much appreciated. I will provide my code below.

hub.php

```
 <?php

  // this file connects to the database
  include("includes/connect.inc.php");

  session_start();

  if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $uid        = $_SESSION['id'];
  } 

//If the search input was submitted then run
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    // turn that the user searched into a varible
    $searchQ = $_POST['search'];
    // delete any symbols for security
    $searchQ = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchQ);
    // Define varibles before the loop
    $searchArray = array();
    $searchIndex = 0;

    // Search through these columns inside the main database
    $searchQuery = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE 
        title   LIKE '%" . mysqli_escape_string( $searchQ ) . "%' 
    ");

    // count the number of results
    $searchCount = mysqli_num_rows($searchQuery);
    if($searchCount != 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchQuery)){
            $titleSearch     = $row['title'];
            $dateSearch      = $row['date'];

            // buile the array which will hold all the results
            $searchArray[$searchIndex] = array($titleSearch, $dateSearch);
            $searchIndex++;
        }
    }
}
// End of search php



<form id="search" action="hub.php" method="POST">
    <div id="searchIcon"></div>
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

here is the connect file | It is used for a bunch of other forms and loops which work fine.

```
<?php

    $host = "MYHOSTINGDOMAIN";
    $username = "MYUSERNAME";
    $password = "MYPASSWORD";
    $db = $username;

    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

I get this error

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   /services/webpages/d/i/digitalicon.ca/public/hub.php on line 42
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in /services/webpages/d/i/digitalicon.ca/public/hub.php on
>   line 45

Comment: Whats the errors? Have you debugged?\

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so with the updated information provided, it looks as if you're connecting via mysqli_* functions and then using the mysql_* functions in this script (switching to mysqli was presumably part of your login changes).

So you need to update your script to become this:

```
<?php

// this file connects to the database
include("includes/connect.inc.php");

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $uid        = $_SESSION['id'];
} 

// //If the search input was submitted then run
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    // turn that the user searched into a varible
    $searchQ = $_POST['search'];
    // delete any symbols for security
    $searchQ = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchQ);
    // Define varibles before the loop
    $searchArray = array();
    $searchIndex = 0;

    // Search through these columns inside the main database
    $searchQuery = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE 
        title   LIKE '%" . mysqli_escape_string( $searchQ ) . "%' or 
        date    LIKE '%" . mysqli_escape_string( $searchQ ) . "%' 
    ");

    // count the number of results
    $searchCount = mysqli_num_rows($searchQuery);
    if($searchCount != 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchQuery)){
            $titleSearch     = $row['title'];
            $dateSearch      = $row['date'];

            // buile the array which will hold all the results
            $searchArray[$searchIndex] = array($titleSearch, $dateSearch);
            $searchIndex++;
        }
    }
}
// End of search php
```

This includes my initial fix of actually querying the database where you were previously just escaping the string.

Comment: I just changed it to the example you provided but it didnt seem to change anything. I do notice though when I changed it, the color identifier in my texted editor changed the mysql font from pink to yellow(as if it were just one string not a mysql string) right after the first "or" in the query.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting when running the code?

Comment: It looks like your script isn't actually connecting to the database based on the errors you've posted. Can you include the code contained in `include("includes/connect.inc.php");` so we can view your connection code? (Make sure to redact the username/password for the connection)

Comment: Just added the connect file, I dont understand why it would cause me issues though because I use it for a bunch of other things in my site as well. Could the session possibly be causing some sort of issue because it work fine before I got all my sessions work properly.

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are connecting via mysqli_* but this particular script is still using the mysql_* functions. I've updated my answer to reflect the changes you'll need.

Comment: Hi, I just pasted your code in and I am a little closer for sure but I am still getting errors. I just updated what my code looks like now and the new errors I am getting. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: I Think I got it, I needed to add the connect variable as the first parameter of the mysqli query